# The \pgf@x and \pgf@y commands

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two questions:

- How the commands `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` are defined?
- How to use these commands inside the `\pgfdeclareshape` command?

Comment: These are dimensions that are used in a lot of internal pgf and Ti*k*Z commands, and they get repeatedly overwritten. The `@` indicates that a "normal" user is not supposed to mess around with these, but when you define your own shape you'll most likely need them. To answer your question, they are not uniquely defined.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: read the section `117 Adding libraries to pgf: temporary registers` page `1208` of `3.1.4b` TikZ manual

Comment: For the declaration of shapes, the roles of `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` from section **101.7 Internals of How Point Commands Work** of the pgfmanual v 3.1.4a is relevant.